# MySQL INNER JOIN returning duplicate results

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t2.* ,t3.title ,t3.locale as locale FROM DocumentsTopics t1 
INNER JOIN Documents t2 ON t1.di_name = t2.di_name 
INNER JOIN DocumentsContent t3 ON t2.di_name = t3.di_name 
WHERE locale='locale' 
AND (t3.title LIKE '%searchphrase%' OR t3.summary LIKE '%searchphrase%') ORDER BY t2.uploadDate asc 
LIMIT 0, 100
```

This query returns several of the records twice and even 3 times. I noticed that when I change the part in ()

from this below

```
 (t3.title LIKE '%searchphrase%' OR t3.summary LIKE '%searchphrase%')
```

to the line below, I do not get multiple results.

```
   (t3.title LIKE '%searchphrase%')
```

But I do need my query to check in more then one field.

Please help

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` - it will collapse your duplicates.

Comment: That's how joins work. They join every row with any matching row according to the join condition you specified.